# How to quickly configure a pppd server on "linux"?

Tags: linux, pppoe

Purpose: boot an Ubuntu 10.10 LiveCD, and run a pppoe server on it...
I thought it's just like this:
1) I create a user
2) I run "pppd require-pap"
...but noooo

why? I'm trying to run pppd but it gives the:
pppd: The remote system is required to authenticate itself
pppd: but I couldn't fin any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.

Can anyone post it in a few lines how to do it?

I just need a pppd server using *only* PAP [i don't really need that users can log in, etc.], because i just want that that the clients *try* to log in with PAP, so I can tcpdump the username/passwords, because we don't have them.

Thank you!! :\ it's getting important..

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a lot more then just configure pppd options; you also need the PPPoE server to handle the ethernet stuff.

```
#!/bin/bash

killall pppoe-server

MAX=250
INTERFACE=eth0
BASE=10.10.100.1 # clients get an IP starting here.
MYIP=10.10.10.252 # set to your eth0 IP address.
/usr/sbin/pppoe-server -T 60 -I $INTERFACE -N $MAX -C CANADA -S PPPoE7 -L $MYIP -R $BASE
```

This is basically the script we use with our test DSLAM and PPPoE stuff in our office. We are running on Debian Lenny so it should all work similiarly on Ubuntu. You also may need an /etc/ppp/pppoe-server-options file with just the following in it:

```
login
```

You might also need to at least add the username (with a bogus password) in /etc/ppp/pap-secrets?

The man page for pppd says to use the following in the options file to disable CHAP:

```
disable-chap
```